# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel in MABS

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2013

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship 
>   for the SSL/TLS secure channel

I am facing the above error in MABS (Microsoft Azure BizTalk Services).

Any particular solution for this?

According to my knowledge it may be either a certificate error or an database access error. I am getting this while deploying where as building is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely your ACS namespace, issuer, or access key is incorrect.  Building wouldn't give you this error, as building is only done in the local environment.  Deploying actually makes a secure connection with MABS so upload your assemblies.

Another option to check would be to make sure that your current firewall rules allow for the proper connections.

Comment: This may be because of database access or some certification issue also??

Comment: Yes, but deploying to Azure involves entering your ACS information.  It's likely that information was entered incorrectly.